# How to use Vuejs to replace this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this code below :

```js
log(n) {
  $('#log').append('<div></div>').append(document.createTextNode(n));     
},
```

The jquery function will inject text into the code below :

```html
<div id='log'></div>
```

How to do this by using Vue.js? please help me
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to add an text message to a specific HTML element, there is no need to use VueJs for this. You could just rewrite the jQuery code into vanilla Javascript:

```js
function log(n) {
  const divElement = document.createElement("div")
  const textNode = document.createTextNode(n)
  document.getElementById('log')
    .append(divElement);

  divElement.append(textNode);
}


// run
log('hello world')
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```